# How to replace GraphQL variable if not available?

Tags: react-native, graphql

I have a strange question regrading a query request I am trying to do.

So while the `b_id` variable is undefined I want to replace with null in the following example. I've tried by adding `props.business.getUserBusiness[0]._id || null` but still come back with undefined error.

```
export default compose(
    withApollo,
    graphql(GET_ME, { name: "getMe" }),
    graphql(GET_USER_BUSINESS, { name: "business" }),
    graphql(GET_BUSINESS_JOBS,
        {
            name: "businessJobs",
            skip: (props) => !props.business || !props.business.getUserBusiness, 
            options: (props) => (
                {
                    variables:
                    {
                        b_id: props.business.getUserBusiness[0]._id
                    }
                }
            )
        }),
)(Dashboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

`props.business.getUserBusiness` can be defined while `props.business.getUserBusiness[0]` can be undefined

From earlier question (query) ... you won't get an array but object, try

```
        skip: (props) => !props.business || !props.business.getUserBusiness._id, 
        options: (props) => (
            {
                variables:
                {
                    b_id: props.business.getUserBusiness._id
                }
            }
        )
```

Defining a variable for unused (skip) query is not useless ?